# I Want To Store Four Upcoming Dates Into Database?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to Store four upcoming dates in database with increment of 7 days from the  current date. For example today date is `2016/05/02` and next four dates are 
`2016/05/09,2016/05/16,2016/05/23,2016/05/30`.

I'm trying to do this with this method:

```
$today = date('Y/m/d', strtotime('+0 days'));
$_SESSION['nextweek'] = $today;
for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++){
    $j = $i + 7;
    $_SESSION['nextweek'] = date($_SESSION['nextweek'], strtotime('$j days'));   
}
```

Comment: Bravo, now store it in database. Why you are storing in session?

Comment: So what issue are you having?

Comment: Return The Current Date Only Which is 2016/05/02

Comment: You do realize that your loop overwrites the date every time it runs?

Comment: I am new in php. According to my opinion it should do this because when loop is completed in value should be changed

Comment: Correct, it will change but the first time it loops the value will be: 10th, then 11th, then 12th etc. of may and not increment by 7 as you want.

Comment: Wait.. mayby i'm not thinking clear. But either way your loop is not correct

Comment: I think you should use an array instead of a session variable, because that way you can save all values and dump them to see if something is wrong. So instead of $_SESSION use $arr[$i] and below the loop you can use var_dump($arr); to see what values you got.

Comment: When Loop Run First Time Its Value is 1 and in second line of the loop i store the value of **$i**  with the increment of 7 into **$j veriable** then i am try to overwrite the session value

Comment: i don't think so we need an array because when session is overwrite i value inserted into the database.

Comment: Yes but the second time $i is 2 and then you add 7. The third time $i is 3 and you add 7. Basically you are not going to get a 7 increment when you do like that. You see that, right? If you only use $i it will be much easier. instead of $j = .... use $i =$i+6; and replace $j as key in the loop to $i and you will have your 7 incrementing loop.

Comment: I know here is problem in logic to generate full coming with increment of 7 days but point it is should generate the last date when loop is completed

Comment: @NajeedUrRehman I added a edit on the answer below, if it gets an OK I think it will work

Comment: look at my answer below

Comment: @NajeedUrRehman does it work?

Comment: @Andreas I am not test your code yet but i think i got the better solution which was provided by ** Pedro Lobito**. it is an class of date and its work perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you're tying to achieve, but to have **4 increments** of **7 days** from the **current date**, you can (and **should**) use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
<?php
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Lisbon' );
$datetime = new DateTime();
for( $i=1 ; $i<5; $i++ ){
    $datetime->modify( '+7 day' );
    $_SESSION['nextweek'] = $datetime->format( 'Y-m-d' );
    echo $_SESSION['nextweek'];
}
/*
2016-05-09
2016-05-16
2016-05-23
2016-05-30
*/
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/XvaOi5)

Comment: If the commented stuff is the output, then it's incorrect

Comment: I thought so, I didn't even read your code but was sure you made a misstake with only the output :-)

Comment: I always test my code and sometimes it can get confuse... :)

Comment: It Work Thank You Bro :) GOD Bless You

Comment: You **Pedro Lobito** used \n in php

Comment: Pedro Lobito Yes Bro Got it Thank You

Comment: @NajeedUrRehman If my answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer, thank you !

Comment: @Pedro Lobito I was already do this. Thansk for this **The DateTime class**

Answer (score 0):

Your loop must be something like this

```
$today = date('Y/m/d',strtotime('+0 days'));
$_SESSION['nextweek'] = $today;
$j=7;
for($i= 0;$i<4;$i++)
{
    $nextdate = date('Y/m/d',strtotime("+$j day", strtotime('+0 days'))); 
    $j+=7;
    print_r($nextdate); 
    echo "<br />";
}
```

This output

```
2016/05/09
2016/05/16
2016/05/23
2016/05/30
```

Comment: I don't think so because when first time loop is correct because i start from 7 but when second time the loop value is 8 then it increment into date 8 and next time 9 and so on until the condition is false

Comment: Yes because you were updating $i days where session next week was already updated with 7 days, you might be getting 7th day then 15th day I think

Comment: @Sameer that is not the expected output

Comment: But its not the correct dates, look at the question

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = date('Y/m/d',strtotime('+0 days'));
$_SESSION['nextweek'] = $today;
for($i= 7;$i<=28;$i++){
$_SESSION['nextweek']= date($_SESSION['nextweek'],strtotime('$i days'));  
$i =$i+6; // now it increments with 7 days.
}
```

This should give you the correct dates

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i= 1;$i<5;$i++){
    $j = $i*7;
    $_SESSION['nextweek']= date('Y/m/d',strtotime("+".$j." days"));   
}
```